# Magento 2.2.1: Customer custom attribute, sort order irregularity

Tags: magento-2.2.1

I have added a Customer custom attribute called *about*,

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'about', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'About',
        'input' => 'text',
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'system' => 0,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
    ]
);
```

The attribute is shown in Customer's Account information tab, and is successfully saving and retrieving.

**The only issue is with the `sort_order`, whatever number I gave there (10, 10000, 500), the attribute always shows at the top of the list (above *Associate to Website*).**

I have tried cache clean and flush, also upgraded and compiled.

What should I do to bring it to the bottom of the list?

Answer (score 4):

I have added a customer attribute "Business Name" through following installation script and it's showing at the bottom of Customer's Account information tab

```
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'business_name',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Bussiness Name',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'default' => 'NULL',
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 216,
            'position' => 216,
            'system' => false,
        ]);
        $business_name = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY,'business_name')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit'],
        ]);
        $business_name->save();
```

I think this is because of "position" property.
Please try with above code and let me know if it's still not work.

Answer (score 0):

The sort order will be save in `ui_bookmark` table in database. Find the record of listing file which you are using and delete it after you change the sort order. After that try clean cache by:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Hope it help you!
Here is my `ui_bookmark` table:
[image]